# Get the last inserted string Id in SQL Server & C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, last-insert-id

I have a `DataTable` BonLivraison with a primary key that is a string with the format `2016/` + increment number. I used this code to generate this primary key:

```
SqlCommand cmdRow = new SqlCommand("select TOP(1) CodeBonLivraison from BonLivraison ORDER BY 1 DESC", con);

string LastCode = (string)cmdRow.ExecuteScalar();
string getID = LastCode.Split('/')[1];
int getIntID = Convert.ToInt32(getID);

numeroBonReceptionTextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "/" + (getIntID + 1).ToString();
```

This code generates primary keys normally `2016/1`...`2016/2`....until `2016/10` it re-generates `2016/10` which is primary key violation.

So how modify this code to get last inserted key and get 2016/11...2016/12...

Comment: I guess, after `"2016/10"` you have not updated this value in `CodeBonLivraison` column. Just recheck your code again.

Comment: No i used this code to generates Id and after 2016/10 the SqlCommand retuns always 2016/9 and add 1 so we get 2016/10 always

Comment: Did you try debug it?

Comment: Obviously he does not. Stackoverflow is a replacement for doing your own work.

Comment: Yes i tried to debug and the exception is primary key violation and i used MessageBox.Show(LastCode) and i get 2016/9

Comment: @TomTom i havent asked to do my own work i asked for help

Comment: becuase the column is string. after 2016/9, you inserted 2016/10. But subsequent SELECT TOP 1  .. . ORDER BY CodeBonLivraison  DESC will still gives you 2016/9. Adding 1 and trying to INSERT will gives you pk violation

Comment: please refer to the answer i just posted

Comment: @Squirrel yes i know that...how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query to

```
select TOP(1) CodeBonLivraison 
from   BonLivraison 
ORDER BY convert(int,
                 right(CodeBonLivraison, charindex('/', reverse(CodeBonLivraison )) - 1)
                 ) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr @Squirrel. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select TOP(1) CodeBonLivraison 
from BonLivraison 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(CodeBonLivraison, 6, LEN(CodeBonLivraison ) - 5) as int) DESC
```